# Why is my page so wide?

Tags: css, slider, nivo-slider

Take a look at my website using Firefox or Chrome : [BehineHost](http://www.behinehost.com).

I just set up and configured "Nivo Slider". Before that all was going well, but now if you open the page with Firefox or Chrome, you'll see a large horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the browser.

I did a lot of checks but found nothing...
How can I fix it?

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously, use "you", not "u".

Comment: And "please", "your" and "I", not "plz" "ur" and "i".

Comment: lol, sorry Laugh Out Load !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text-indent : -9999px`, that's why.

Class that cause it :

```
.nivo-controlNav a {
    background: url("images/bullets.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 19px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 30%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 17px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

If you had looked more carefully, you would have seen the **1 2 3** on the far right.